# Accessing parameters in Request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, request, httprequest

I have a question about obtaining parameters from Request object.

What is the difference between

```
$name = $request->name;
```

OR

`$name = $request->input("name")`;

They show the same behavior. I am asking that from the typing perspective, it is faster to utilize #1 method. But I don't know the difference. Is #1 prone to SQL injections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the first case is just a syntactic sugar for the second. In Laravel, Request implements __get magic function to access its internal properties.

```
public function all()
{
    return array_replace_recursive($this->input(), $this->allFiles());
}

public function __get($key)
{
    $all = $this->all();

    if (array_key_exists($key, $all)) {
        return $all[$key];
    } else {
        return $this->route($key);
    }
}
```

In the first case, if any files were uploaded, Laravel first looks for a property amongst them. And if there is no such param in files or in input, in your first snippet, Laravel also looks for a value amongst route parameters:

To protect your code against SQL injections, you have to use prepared statements/query builder/ORM. You should not escape/change input, so both these functions don't protect you against SQL injections.